# ESXi doesn't show up my hard drive

Tags: vmware-esxi, sata, controller

I have an issue here with my ESXi server from VMware. I added a Dawicontrol "DC4320" Sata Controller to spend my ESXi more space for VMs. I also put some Sata hard drives on it and they are also shown in the BIOS of the Sata Controller.

Now I did a new install of ESXi and I thought that my hard drives are also shown up now but they are not.

Is there anything I could do?

Answer (score 2):

The VMWare [forums suggest it can be beat into submission](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/126918?tstart=9650), but it is officially not supported, and if you have any additional problems with it VMWare will not support that configuration.

Always check that hardware is supported on ESXi *before* buying it: [ESXi Compatibility List](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php)